# Where does Vuex store reside in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Just trying to get my head around Vuex / Nuxt , also quite new to nodejs.

Given that nuxt is a server side rendering app , Where does Vuex "reside" . In standard Vue , Vuex is a client side store. How does it work in Nuxt? Is it still a client side store but just rendered on the server first?

If it stays on the server , then I am just wondering how it handles per user data - or is it somehow shared. thank you.

Comment: This is actually a good question. Hoping someone gives a detailed answer as I am interested how nuxt does it +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### SSR and rehydration:

Both client and server hold the state. When the client makes the first request to load the initial page the state is usually passed through the html document inside a script, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer>window.__NUXT__={"data":[{"name":"server"}],"error":null,"serverRendered":true}</script>
```

Then when the application js load it has to pickup the state, this processed is known as rehydration. From this point the client will maintain the server state in sync.

### Nuxt specifics:

Interesting parts of Nuxt documentation:

- https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data
- https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store

Nuxt Vuex Demo:

https://nuxtjs.org/examples/vuex-store

### Vue SSR:

In addition take a look into vue ssr documentation, it's very detailed and it does a better job explaining how everything fits in:

- https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/hydration.html
- https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/data.html

> we will serialize and inline the state in the HTML. The client-side store can directly pick up the inlined state before we mount the app.

Comment: So how if the store is being passed from the server side to the client  side. How is it synchronized between both client and server. eg: after changes on the client side, user enters a new URL